# npm link and rollupjs cannot find es6 module

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, node-modules, rollup

I'm using rollupjs with babel, node-resolve and commonjs plugins. It works fine as I can `import foo from "foo"` to import `foo` from a npm-package called `foo`.

I now want to contribute to a dependency and test it using `npm link`. So I cloned the repository of the dependency, issued `npm link` inside it's directory and then issued `npm link foo` in my project's directory to use that local copy of `foo`. Now rollupjs throws an error when it comes to `import foo from "foo"` complaining that it cannot find the module `foo`.

Am I missing something or is rollup.js not yet ready for `npm link`ed modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm link` creates symlinks and rollup [doesn't support](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/447) them yet.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is outdated. [Rollup does support symlinks now](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#preservesymlinks)

`plugin-node-resolve` and `plugin-commonjs` should be all the configuration/tooling that is necessary for creating bundles including the symlinked modules.

If one is is experiencing a missing dependency/global variable warnings, it may be beneficial to check the link path.

Comment: The flag/config name for turning it off seems a little backwards, imho, but wanted to point to their documentation highlighting symlink support.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use bare import and use the relative import instead

```
import foo from '../../foo/src/index.js'
```